# Top five current month birthday candidates and greater than today's date using SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need top five current month birthdays candidates and greater than today's date using SQL.

My query to get current month birthday candidates.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_EmployeeInfo WHERE MONTH(DOB) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

But I need top 5 candidates of having current month birthday and greater than today dates.

Date format in my table.

```
2016-10-13 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Top five defined how? And I'm sure you know how to compare dates. Date format doesn't exist in the database since you surely stored the dates as dates and not varchars?

Comment: Upcoming birthday of this month only and need greather than todays date. @Sami Kuhmonen

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using

Comment: Sql server 2008 and below result are not working. @Prdp

Comment: `Top 5` should be on what basis. Is there a column or way to find the order

Comment: Greater then today date, like tomorow or some other dates greather today only for current month. @Prdp

Comment: @mazhar124 - I get that point.. But what am asking is, consider there are 10 candidates having birthday greater than today and with in this month. Now in out of this 10 candidates in what basis I should get `TOP 5`

Comment: Get top five on tomorow basis na. @Prdp

Comment: if tomorrow is not there then catch some next day like that, hope you understand. @Prdp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM   table_employeeinfo 
WHERE  MONTH(DOB) = MONTH(Getdate()) 
       AND DAY(DOB) > DAY(Getdate())
--ORDER BY your_order_column
```

**Note :** Add `ORDER BY` clause to make query more meaningful

Comment: Not getting any values. @Prdp

Comment: I have one date like 1987-10-23 00:00:00.000 in my dob column but not coming one record. @Prdp

Comment: @mazhar124 - so you dont want to consider **year**

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are looking for the five most closest upcoming birthdays. So you would first order the result ascending by birtday and then limit the result to five rows:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_EmployeeInfo WHERE MONTH(DOB) = MONTH(GETDATE())
ORDER BY DOB ASC
LIMIT 5
```

edit: Okay, "greater than today" needs to be put in as an additional condition:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_EmployeeInfo WHERE MONTH(DOB) = MONTH(GETDATE())
AND DOB > NOW()
ORDER BY DOB ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I dont want past birthday of this month, your above query is coming past dates of this month. @Arrmaniac

Comment: the above second query is not working and Its sql server 2008 version. @Arrmaniac

Answer (score 0):

in sql server

```
SELECT top 5 * FROM Table_EmployeeInfo 
WHERE MONTH(DOB) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DOB >= GETDATE()
ORDER BY DOB ASC
```